# Compositional Inverse for the Shifted Exponential Function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, exponential-function

Let $$f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{x}=$$

Looking at the graph in comparison to the exponential function $g(x)=e^x$, it is clear that $f^{-1}(x)$ grows in a similar fashion to $g^{-1}(x)=\ln(x)$.  However, I am pretty sure that there is not a closed form for $f^{-1}$.  Certainly it can not be found by the elementary methods taught in courses such as precalculus, etc.  Consider switching $x$ and $y$ and solving for $y$;

$$x=\frac{e^y-1}{y}\Rightarrow xy+1=e^y$$

I mean, I suppose this is a valid expression, it is just not expressable in function notation.

Why can we not find an expression for $f^{-1}$ in terms of the logarithmic function, since $f$ and $g$ are clearly closely related?

Comment: Not necessarily closed form, but usually the inverse of complicated functions involving exponentials and logs result in the [Lambert-W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). For this example it would be, $$ x= \frac{-yW(-1/(e^{1/y}y))-1}{y}$$

Comment: Yeah, I have seen the lambert function before, though have not studied it at all.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the purpose of representing $f^{-1}$ to prove it is increasing/decreasing or convex/concave over $\mathbb{R}^+$? If so, you may just derive such properties from $f$, that is studied here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2356878/find-whether-the-given-function-is-strictly-increasing-decreasing-in-interval/2360088#2360088

Comment: No, it just seems so strange to me, @JackD'Aurizio, that something so similar to the exponential function does not have an inverse, notationally is really what i mean,  that is similar to the natural logarithmic function.  In terms of a power series representation, the function differ by shifted coefficients, which seems like a basic transformation, and I'm not sure why we can't have a similar phenomenon for the inverse.

Comment: @AveryJessup: $x-\varepsilon\sin(x)$ is very close to the identity function, **but** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation

Comment: transcendental v. algebraic.  Makes perfect sense now.